# Removing band from raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, band, remove

When I process a raster in QGIS it creates a second band. It appears that the band has no useful data. I like to use the Raster Colours Tool and it will not accept a raster with anything more than one band.

How do I remove the extra band?

Comment: What raster processing are you doing that creates the extra band? It sounds like it is generating a mask band.

Comment: I am using the new clipper tool in QGIS 1.7. It is a GDAL_TRANSLATE implementation as far as I know. I use a shapefile mask layer and a no data value of 0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting. If you specify a shapefile as a mask, it uses gdal_warp, and automatically adds -dstalpha to the commandline options.

For now, you could copy the text that appears at the bottom of the dialog box, and paste it into a command line window, removing the -dstalpha option. But this isn't an ideal solution, so I suggest you file a ticket on the [QGIS bug tracker](http://trac.osgeo.org/qgis/) to get it added as an option.

As an alternative but sticking with the command line, you could run gdal_translate on your two-band file, using the option -b 1 to just use the first band for the output.

Band control is definitely something worth having in QGIS I reckon, so it might be worth adding that to the bug tracker as a requested feature.

Answer (score 9):

select in Toolbox: Rearrange bands. And remove band

Comment: By far the easiest option! Especially if you just want to drop just one band from a multi-band raster.

Comment: Well, I select one band (the one to keep) and after processing, the other bands are still in the new product.

Comment: Maybe you have some specific raster that the algorithm cannot process, try resaving it to another format, I just tried the PNG 4 bands file, everything is fine, only the selected band remains...

Answer (score 0):

Try "GDAL miscellaneous raster calculator". I had the same problem.  In the dialog box choose the raster file for the A band, and leave the other band as not selected.  In the calculation gdalnumeric command text box type A*1.  The raster file created will have only one band.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use QGIS raster calculator:

Expression: `"my_raster@1"`

Click `current layer extent`

and save as a new single band raster.